# Como alinhar os textos dentro de uma tabela em html

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando fazer a tabela do brasileirão para exercitar o conceito de tabelas que aprendi.

Porém quando eu coloco os dados sobre vitórias e derrotas eles ficam todos desorganizados.

```css
table#brasileirao{
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-spacing: 0px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 600px;
    }

table#brasileirao td{
   border:1px solid black;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="brasileirao">
  <tr><td>Clube</td><td>P V E D GP GC SG</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Flamengo</td><td>1 2 3 4 5 6 7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Flamengo</td><td>1 2 3 4 5 6 7</td></tr>
</table>
```

Como eu queria que ficasse:

[image: Como eu queria que ficasse]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fica bom mesmo vc tem que separar cada um desses valores em um TD, assim vc tem um controle melhor do alinhamento dos itens dentro da células e da largura das céluas.

Repare que eu usei a classe `table-layout:fixed`, isso ajuda a deixar a largura das TD mais uniforme, e usei `text-aling:center` para alinhas o conteúdo dentro da TD. Eu deixei a TD dos clubes com 50% da largura da tabela, e os outros dados eu deixei para o `table-layout:fixed` dividir igualmente a largura das TD restantes.

Veja o resultado:

```css
table#brasileirao {
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  border-spacing: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 600px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table#brasileirao td {
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  padding: 10px;
}
td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="brasileirao">
<tr>
  <td>Clube</td>
  <td>P</td>
  <td>V</td>
  <td>E</td>
  <td>D</td>
  <td>GP</td>
  <td>GC</td>
  <td>SG</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Flamengo</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Flamengo</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
</tr>
</table>
```